# Add wild card in Remote Site Settings for Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, callout, remote-access

Is it possible to add Wild cards in the remote site settings for HTTP Callouts. For example I have a web service called foo.com. My customers have accounts on my service as customer1.foo.com , customer2.foo.com, etc. Can I have my app whitelist a domain such as *.foo.com. So that any customer can make callout to their account by specifying their account url.

ANy help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Abhinav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. Your clients will have to set the Remote Site Setting theirselves.

Also see this similar discussion: [Dynamically set remote site Setting in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25005/dynamically-set-remote-site-setting-in-apex)