# Remove RemoteSiteSetting from Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, package-install, delete, remote-site

Thanks to @sfdcfox and @AndrewFawcett we were able to figure an elegant way on how to create a dynamic RemoteSiteSetting for the actual salesforce org in order to use MetadataAPI, ToolingAPI and so on:
[Access MetadataAPI via JavaScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45107/access-metadataapi-via-javascript)

Now we did bad earlier and included a longer list of Remote Sites into the managed package... :-(

Is there any chance to get rid of RemoteSiteSetting again? The package is in the wild and in use by a lot of users. So to uninstall it everywhere and let support revert it back to beta seems not to be realistic.

Comment: The best thing I found so far is to deactivate the RemoteSites. So if new users install the package they get a bunch of inactive settings. Still they get warning-popup in the installer and have to confirm it (which is pretty much on the save-side for a peace of inactive configuratin)

Answer (score 0):

As of now (2023) it is possible by just deleting RSS on the managed package org:

Setup -> Remote Site Settings -> find your RSS -> Delete.

This will remove the RSS from the package. However, when you upgrade your customer's orgs, the deprecated (deleted) RSS will still be on their orgs. For the clean installations - there will be no deprecated RSS.