# Can we create Lightning component using sforce connection

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, sforce

I have to create lightning component on click of a button. This should happen in run time.

I tried to SForce connection for the same. But I have to create first AuraDefinitionBundle, then AuraDefinition for Component, controller, helper etc.
I could successfully create a working Lightning component using sforce.

Is this right approach? Will there any different way to achieve this?

Below is the code which I used to create HELPER js.

```
<apex:page controller="TestApex">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <apex:slds />
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.StaticResources, 'StaticResources/js/jquery-2.2.4.js')}"/>
        <script src="../../soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="Api_Session_ID" value="{!$Api.Session_ID}"/>
        <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" id="toggleBtn" >Click Me</button>
        </div>  
    </body>
    <script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$('#toggleBtn').click(function(){
        debugger;
        alert('helo' );
        var pagedata ="({ getMetho : function(cmp, helper){ console.log('Hello!'); } })";
        var connection = sforce.connection;
        connection.sessionId = jQuery('#Api_Session_ID').val();
        var newRecord= new sforce.SObject("AuraDefinition");
        newRecord.AuraDefinitionBundleId  ="0Ab6F000000g2QmSAI"
        newRecord.DefType   = "HELPER";
        newRecord.Format  = "JS";
        newRecord.Source  = pagedata;
        var result = sforce.connection.create([newRecord]);

        alert(result );

    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use sforce.connection.* methods to create metadata. This method only works for "normal" data, like Accounts, Contacts, and Custom Objects. More specifically, sforce.connection.* uses the SOAP API to perform updates, but you need the Tooling API or Metadata API. I would say that using the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm) is probably the easiest method. I suggest you check out the documentation, but in summary, you'll create a AuraDefinitionBundle followed by AuraDefinition objects. You can use a [Composite Request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_requests_composite_composite.htm) in order to simplify deployment and reduce the API usage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But as I am sending this as REST API, I have to add endpoint in remote site settings. I am creating a managed package and want to install it in multiple org. In that case should this be action item to add remote site setting manually?

Comment: @sfdev See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45107) about adding a Remote Site in Visualforce/JavaScript. It should still work.